# My menu vanishes when using overflow-x on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, overflow, hidden

I have a `menu` that's within a div that I hide off screen. When the `menu-button` is pressed I bring the `menu` in to view. Whilst doing this, I shift the visible content of the body over to one side, allowing room for the `menu`.

When I originally did this, I placed `overflow-x:hidden;` in the body and it worked perfectly for desktops. When I loaded the website on to my phone, I noticed that the phone didn't behave the same - it attempt to display the `menu` and all of the content that was on the screen.

I did a little reading and it stated that mobile browsers ignore `overflow-x` when placed in the html or body tags and a wrapper div should be created.

When i made this edit my `menu` vanished. When I click the `menu-button`, the content moves across for the `menu` but it doesn't appear. 
What is going on here? I don't quite understand why the `menu` would disappear. How can I fix this?

The wrapper that I made is....

```css
#body_wrapper{
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
```

```html
<div id="body_wrapper">
  My nav bar...
  My menu...
  my content...    
</div>
```

My website is - http://robingham.co.uk/LUUCC6/index.php

This current edit of the website has the `overflow-x:hidden;` set in the body of the CSS, not the body_wrapper. So the menu displays but it doesn't properly function on a mobile.

Answer (score 0):

### So i fixed my issue! Whoop!

Originally i was using `.animate()` in Jquery for my menu animation. The menu would hide offscreen and using the animate function i would 'slowly'(285px in 0.3s) move the menu in to place on screen. Whilst this worked perfectly fine for desktop browsers where i placed `overflow-x: hidden;` in to the CSS for the `body`. Mobile browsers ignore `overflow-x: hidden;` when placed in the `body`.

Reading around i saw many times about placing `overflow-x: hidden;` in to a wrapper for the body content. Ie.  content . Whilst it indeed stop a scroll bar popping up for the x-axis and content being shrunk, it screwed up my menu - my menu just vanished. For whatever reason putting `overflow-z: hidden;` in to the wrapper didn't agree with the Jquery animate function. I tried placing the menu outside of the wrapper but still no luck. I also tried playing `overflow-x: hidden;` in to both the wrapper and the body with no success.

Okay so time for a new strategy, as i spent far too long playing with my menu to just scrap it.

### **My solution**

I currently have my menu sat outside of the wrapper and so i've decided to keep `overflow-x: hidden;` in both the body and the wrapper. Maybe an overkill but at least i know it'll function as intended regardless of the browser. Maybe in the future, i'll have a little faff with putting the menu back within the wrapper and only have the `overflow-x: hidden;` in the wrapper and see if it still works. (I kind of don't like having many things that do the same/similar job scattered everywhere. It feels a little messy.)

The menu has three associated classes attached to it now. `menu`, `menu_hide`, and `menu_show`. `menu` has all of my CSS formatting. I use the `menu_hide`and `menu_show` classes to hide and show the menu.

My default HTML for the menu looks like this. Note that it has two classes.

```
<div class="menu menu_hide">
```

My CSS for the hide and show look like this. Note that `transition` does the same job as the Jquery `.animate()` function.

```
.menu_show{
    transition: 0.3s;
    left: 0px;
}

.menu_hide{
    transition: 0.3s;
    left: -285px;
}
```

My JS looks like this. Note that i toggle between the menu showing and hiding classes everytime i hit the menu button.

```
$('.icon-menu').click(function() {
     $('.menu').toggleClass( "menu_show menu_hide" );
});
```